# Docker container fails to respond after ping in azure app service

Tags: azure, docker

I have a dotnet 8 Web API running inside a Docker container hosted on Azure App Service.
Locally, with Docker Desktop the container runs fine and can access the API but once I deploy it to Azure App Service, I get the following from the logs:

```
2024-03-07T17:47:57.238819477Z warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[15]
2024-03-07T17:47:57.238908078Z       Overriding HTTP_PORTS '8080' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'http://+:5000'.
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861723924Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861762026Z       Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861766826Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861770226Z       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861773626Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861777126Z       Hosting environment: Dev
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861780326Z info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-03-07T17:47:57.861783826Z       Content root path: /app
2024-03-07T17:50:46.588Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-api-shared-sano_0_12fa4cb9. Elapsed time = 171.6636177 sec
2024-03-07T17:51:01.721Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-api-shared-sano_0_12fa4cb9. Elapsed time = 186.7960734 sec
2024-03-07T17:51:17.534Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-api-shared-sano_0_12fa4cb9. Elapsed time = 202.6093028 sec
2024-03-07T17:51:32.639Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-api-shared-sano_0_12fa4cb9. Elapsed time = 217.7143098 sec
2024-03-07T17:51:45.746Z ERROR - Container app-api-shared-sano_0_12fa4cb9 for site app-api-shared-sano did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.8218418 sec
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8181
ENV DOTNET_URLS=http://+:8181

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api/WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj", "Api/WebAPI/"]
COPY ["Api/Application/Application.csproj", "Api/Application/"]
COPY ["Api/Domain/Domain.csproj", "Api/Domain/"]
COPY ["Api/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Api/Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api/WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api/WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY .env.local ./
COPY .env.staging ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

As Startup Command in Azure App Service configuration, I have the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8181 --env-file .env.staging web-api:latest
```

I'm not sure why it behaves this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are deploying your app?

Comment: It gets pushed to a container registry during CI/CD process

Answer (score 0):

#### To deploy a docker container webapps follow these steps:

- Create a Azure Container Registry and push your Image to the container registry. there are are multiple ways to push the Image to container registry:

  1. Using bash docker command

  ```bash
  az acr login -n <azure container registry name>
  docker tag <dockerimage>:<tag> <azure container registry name>.azure.io/ <imagename>:<tag>  # any image name and tag can be as per your choice for ACR
  docker push <azure container registry name>.azure.io/ <imagename>:<tag>
  ```

  2. using Visual Studio 2022
     [image]
     [image]
     Create new registry or you can select your the pre-deployed registry from the listed Resource groups.
     [image]
- After image pushed to Azure Container registry Create a Web app by selecting docker container
- In Docker section select `Azure Container Registry` in Image source choose your ACR, Image and tag

> Note :- enable admin user in you ACR by going to `ACR ->access keys`

[image]

[image]

- Deploy your web app.
- To run the image you need to create a Container instance
- Create a Azure container instance with the same Registry and Image and tag
  [image]

I have used a sample App from VS 2022 to deploy.

##### My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication7/WebApplication7.csproj", "WebApplication7/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication7/WebApplication7.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication7"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication7.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication7.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication7.dll"]
```

## `OUTPUT`:

Open your Web Application URL with your correct route.

[image]

Comment: I have no problem deploying a containerized app, the problem is that the container does respond inside the app service.

Comment: @Gericke Did you create a container instance to run your image? after its pushed to registry?

Comment: @Gericke After pushing the image there should be a container instance to run your Image.

Comment: yes it gets pushed to Azure Container Registry, and App Service is configured for docker container. As you can see in the logs the container starts up but doesn't respond to any request so the application fails to start up